# If matrix $\sum_0^\infty C^k$ is convergent, how can I prove that $A(\sum_0^\infty C^k)B$ is convergent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

For an $n \times n$ matrix $C$ and If $\sum_0^\infty C^k$ is convergent, how can I prove that for two matrices $A$ and $B$, $A(\sum_0^\infty C^k)B$ is convergent?

It seems quite obvious that you just multiply the convergent matrix sum with two constant matrices.

So, it has got to be convergent.

But I don't know how to prove it..

Comment: I edited your post to $\LaTeX$-ify your math, and to correct the grammar and spelling a bit.  Hope it's OK.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to note that the map
$$
X \mapsto AXB
$$
is continuous.  As Marc van Leeuwen notes below, 
$$
A(\sum_{k=0}^N C^k)B = \sum_{k=0}^N AC^kB
$$
so that the limit must be $\sum_{k=0}^\infty AC^kB$, which converges (by our statement of continuity).

Comment: could you explain more please, Can't understand your hint..

Comment: The function given by $f(X) = AXB$ is a continuous function form $\Bbb R^{n \times n}$ to some other space of matrices.  It follows that $f$ takes convergent sequences to convergent sequences.

Comment: +1, nice!. would you be kind enough to give a reference for this?

Comment: @dineshdileep it is sufficient to note that $f$ is a [bounded linear operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator)

Comment: Maybe one should also note the (fairly obvious, but not more so than continuity) point that the operator is linear, so it commutes with finite sums.

Answer (score 0):

If the series converges to $M = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} C^k$ then one has, using as norm the sum of squares (or sum of absolute values if it is a complex matrix) of the elements of the matrix:

$$
||A \sum_{k=0}^N C^k B - AMB|| = ||A(\sum_{k=0}^N C -M)B|| \leq ||A||||B|| \epsilon
$$
for $N$ large enough, from whence the convergence follows.

Comment: where did you use a norm of the matrix? I can only see the absoulute sign.

Comment: It is a matter of convention, the usual notation for the norm is the double line, I meant $||A||= \sqrt{\sum_{i,j} |A_{ij}|^2 }$